# R matrix order by multiple columns (more than 100 columns)

Tags: r, matrix

I have a **matrix** which has more than **100 columns**. I would like to **sort** the matrix according to first col, then sec col, ... , etc.
I know that for small numbers of col, I can do it this way using order function:

```
test2 <- test[order(test[,1],test[,2],test[,3],test[,4], test[,5], test[,6]),]
```

Is there an efficient way to do this if I have more than 100 col and I don't need to specify 1 to 100 col. Maybe using a loop or something?

Thanks so much!
Bernice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your matrix looks something like this:

```
set.seed(47)
x = matrix(rpois(10 * 20, lambda = 1), nrow = 10)
```

When we want to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to a function, `do.call` is a good choice; it lets us pass a list of arguments to a function.

For `order`, each argument we want to pass is a column of the matrix, so we need to make a list of the columns of the matrix. Luckily, a data frame is essentially that, so we can just coerce with `as.data.frame` followed by `as.list`.

```
ordering = do.call(what = order, args = as.list(as.data.frame(x)))
```

This gives us a row ordering that can be applied in the usual way:

```
x[ordering, ]
```

*Note:* The above code will order by *all the columns*, with priority given to earlier columns. To order by *only some columns*, subset the matrix in the `ordering` definition, then proceed as above.

```
# order by even columns
ordering = do.call(
    what = order, args = as.list(as.data.frame(x[, seq(2, ncol(x), by = 2)]))
)
```